# Porque no puedo visualizar archivos Jasper en otro equipo

Tags: java, jar, jasper

Tengo un proyecto en netbeans el cual utiliza archivos Jasper y Jrxml, librería jasperreports-6.0.0.jar
pero al crear el ejecutable y llevarlo a otra pc en windows, al ejecutar el aplicativo carga sin ningun problema pero no puedo visualizar los reportes, algún le ha sucedido esto?

Codigo:

```
     try {
        Conexion con = new Conexion();
        Connection conn = con.getConexion();
        
        JasperReport reporte = null;
        String path="src\\Reportes\\Empleados_Inactivos.jasper"; 
        
        Map parametro = new HashMap();
      //  parametro.put("idcolaborador", id);
        
        reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
        
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametro, conn);
       
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);
        
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        
        view.setVisible(true);
        
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IFrmSueldoEmpleado.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: La ruta para buscar los .jasper es estática o dinámica?

Comment: Para ver  mejor tu problema, agrega parte de tu código

Comment: Si, es estática, acabo de agregar el código y ruta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que la ruta del jasper esta ya espesificada en tu pc.

Por eso en tu pc si funciona el reporte.

El otra pc tendrías que crear la misma ruta con las carpetas y reportes específicos para que los puedas visualizar

Y en la otra pc no esta especificada la ruta.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).